# Windows 7 x64 doesn't suspend

Tags: windows-7, virtualbox, suspend

I have a Windows 7 x64 OS on a M5A97 PLUS motherboard with a FX6300 and one 8GB DDR3 module.
The graphic board is an NVIDIA GeForce 8400 GS.
Have two disk; main an 480GB PNY SSD(about 8 months of use), secondary an 1TB Samsung HD103SI.

The problem is that when I hit the suspend button from the keyboard it shut off both screens but doesn't suspend the rest of the PC, even the keyboard still alive because I can turn on the Capslock and Numlock LEDs.
The reset doesn't work either; the only way is by holding the power button.

I read the Event log and seems to be some trouble with the disk and also an application called Asus Fan Speed Control, or something like that.

Also I read that VirtualBox can cause this coin of problems, and that was one of the application that I have running at that moment.

Now I have Firefox 49.0.1 running and Windows Disk Manager open and can go to suspend mode with no problem.

Is there any way to know what is preventing Windows from going into sleep mode?

Comment: So if you don't load the VirtualDrove drivers does it work?

Comment: What is VirtualDrove?

Comment: The application you believe is causing the problem.  "Is there any way to know what is preventing Windows from going into sleep mode?" There is a command you can run that helps you diagnose which applications are blocking the sleep state but easier to not load your normal programs and one by one load them until you find which one it is

Comment: if you are talking about powercfg -requests I get nothing until I start VirtualBox and at that moment I get:  
SYSTEM:
[DRIVER] Realtek High Definition Audio (HDAUDIO\FUNC_01&VEN_10EC&DEV_0887&SUBSYS
_10438576&REV_1003\4&1328e1bf&0&0001)
An audio stream is being used.

Comment: I am talking about that, and based on the output, the blocking driver is your Realtek device driver which is the reason you could suspened your machine while in Safe Mode (it wasn't being loaded) do the same in a normal configuration manually and see if you can verify thats the problem device driver.

Comment: It looks like VirtualBox is creating the audio stream for the VM.